# Selenium Webdriver getText from element which has hypephen/dash

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I need to check element in my website. From online service I receive data and sometimes I don't have worth and application display dash "-"

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    if (SmeValue.getText().contains(" - ")) {
        System.out.println("no worth");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("worth was displayed");
    }
}
```

Currently I still receive println - worth was displayed despite of no worth in this element. I tried to use equals instead of contains but no result.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting the SmeValue element

Comment: In this class I have only elements from page and methods.

Comment: How is `SmeValue` initialised? Can you show the code for that? Doesn't matter which class it's in

Comment: I initialize this in different class with @Test clause.
`
@Test(priority = 4)
    public void exampleTest() throws InterruptedException {
        pok.test();
    }
`

Comment: That doesn't show how SmeValue is being initialised... I am asking for something like `Element SmeValue = ...;`

Comment: @FindBy(id = "client-smes")
    public WebElement SmeValue;

Comment: Is there only 1 div with clients-smes as the ID? Have you tried to log out the text? `System.out.println(SmeValue.getText());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print SmeValue.getText() first and then try to validate it. Also you are using contains method , so just use "-" inside conatins method, no need to add leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I use "-" in contains method and the same. Still println 'worth was displayed'

Comment: Did you print and observe the value before if condition

Comment: I had to increase Thread.sleep() and everything works. Thanks for help